# How to make all the fontawesome5 icons in a document small?

Tags: fontawesome, fontawesome5

I found that the fontawesome5 icons always a little larger than the text next to them. So I should type `some text before \small\faIcon{youtube}\normalsize some text after...`, it's a little trouble. Could I have a method to change all the fontawesome5 icons smaller in a document?

What's more, I know I can `\def\smallfaIcon#1{\small\faIcon{#1}\normalsize}`, but this method cannot fundamentally solve the problem, and this like change the original command of the package, I hope the solution is s better not this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, `fontawesome5` should have a `scale` option.
Here's what you get normally

[image]

Unfortunately, the [other given answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/713173/4427) is not really good (see at the end for a comparison).

The idea *can* work, but in a different way. Here the scaling is 80% than the default size in all font sizes. You may want to experiment with the factor.

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}% if you use Computer Modern fonts
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontawesome5}

\makeatletter
\AddToHook{cmd/faIcon/before}{%
  \begingroup\fontsize{\fpeval{\f@size*0.8}}{0}\selectfont
}
\AddToHook{cmd/faIcon/after}{\endgroup}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

{\Huge X\faIcon{youtube}Y\par}

some text before \faIcon{youtube} some text after...

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Comparison with the other answer

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontawesome5}

\AddToHook{cmd/faIcon/before}{\begingroup\small}
\AddToHook{cmd/faIcon/after}{\endgroup}

\begin{document}

{\Huge X\faIcon{youtube}Y\par}

some text before \faIcon{youtube} some text after...

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `\Huge` it's exaggerated, but you'd get similar bad result in every font size.

Comment: Elegant! Firstly I test the other solution, I was thinking what if I used other font size, and in the `fontawesome5` document, some logo with the `regular` option should use the first optional variable of the command `\faIcon[regular]{...}`, and the other solution used the `xparse` that has `killed` the first optional variable, it's so awful. So this solution is the best solution for the problem! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

You could patch the command like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\AddToHook{cmd/faIcon/before}{\begingroup\small}
\AddToHook{cmd/faIcon/after}{\endgroup}

\begin{document}

some text before \faIcon{youtube} some text after...

some text before \small\faIcon{youtube}\normalsize\ some text after...

\end{document}
```

If you don't want a small icon, but just a smaller icon, you could use the `relsize` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{relsize}
\AddToHook{cmd/faIcon/before}{\begingroup\smaller}
\AddToHook{cmd/faIcon/after}{\endgroup}

\begin{document}

some text before \faIcon{youtube} some text after...

some text before \small\faIcon{youtube}\normalsize\ some text after...

{\Huge\faIcon{youtube}test}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, not really… Try `{\Huge\faIcon{youtube}}`

Comment: @egreg This gives a small icon, as expected. Why is this a problem?

Comment: Then try `{\scriptsize\faIcon{youtube}}`, where you get a *larger* icon.

Comment: It gives a small icon in all cases, that's what I think the question asks for. Otherwise it would ask for a smaller icon: "How to make all the fontawesome5 icons in a document small?"

Comment: Quoting the OP: “I found that the fontawesome5 icons always a little larger than the text next to them.”